# MPF Ploting CandleStick

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need help in understanding the following code and to trouble shoot the error.

```
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 31)
df = web.get_data_morningstar("nvda",  start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = df.drop('Symbol',axis=1)

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df = df[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]

df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(mdates.date2num)
quotes = [tuple([df.Date,
                 df.Open,
                 df.High,
                 df.Low,
                 df.Close,
                 df.Volume]) ]
#print(quotes)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
#fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6, colorup='b', colordown='r')
plt.grid(True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

The error is "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." the error occurs on the candlestick function call.

Comment: Can you supply some exemplary data so we can try the code?

Comment: @Dux, print(quotes) will give [(0    736815.0
1    736816.0
2    736817.0
3    736818.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64, 0    224.57
1    227.00
2    227.60
3    231.83
Name: Open, dtype: float64, 0    227.2500
1    228.8000
2    234.0500
3    239.1889
Name: High, dtype: float64, 0    222.20
1    225.25
2    225.77
3    231.13
Name: Low, dtype: float64, 0    227.14
1    226.31
2    232.99
3    239.06
Name: Close, dtype: float64, 0     6344727
1     6706185
2    11078640
3    10016538
Name: Volume, dtype: int64)]

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the `quotes` is a list with only one element(a tuple), you should change it to `quotes = tuple([df.Date, df.Open, df.High, df.Low, df.Close, df.Volume])`.  I'm not sure, just try it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quotes. `mpf.candlestick_ohlc` expects a list or tuple containing elements like this:

```
[date, open, high, low, close, volume]
```

However, your quotes has only one element, the tuple. If you remove the outer list, your quotes has 6 elements, `dates`, `opens`, ...

To fix this, create quotes like this:

```
quotes = df.values.tolist()
```

This way, it produces a figure with 4 candlesticks (not showing it here, since I had to heavily tweak your data to get it running).